# What does $ 5 \bigotimes 5 = 10 \bigoplus 5$ mean for SU(5) Lie group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is anyone familiar with this algebra from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM8LoUBlkaE) (at 12:00), which seems to be related to Lie decomposition of the SU(5) group?

$$ 5 \bigotimes 5 = 10 \bigoplus 15$$

[image]

Other examples given are:

$$ 5 \bigotimes \bar 5 = 1 \bigoplus 24$$
$$ \bar 5 \bigotimes 10 = 5 \bigoplus 45$$
$$ 5 \bigotimes 10 = 40 \bigoplus \bar {10}$$
$$ 10 \bigotimes 10 = 50 \bigoplus 45 \bigoplus 5$$

Could anyone explain the step-by-step algebra in order to get at this equality $ 5 \bigotimes 5 = 10 \bigoplus 15$, please?

Comment: A couple of quick points: That notation is quite physics-y and as noted in the answer that last 5 should be a 15. The number denotes a irreducible representation by its dimension. The bar over a number denotes the conjugate representation which in this particular example (as it is a unitary representation) coincides with the dual representation which is also the same as $\bigwedge^4 V$ in this case. The box notation you can also read up on under the name Young diagrams (and Young tableaux, etc.)

Comment: Obviously we run into some problems with that notation when there are several nonisomorphic representations of the same dimension but for $SU(n)$ you can get away with it at least in low dimensions (using bars to distinguish between a rep and its conjugate).

Comment: @Callum thank you very much, i think i understand Young's tableaux method now without the conjugation. Could you elaborate as how to convert the conjugate representation, eg. $\bar {10}$ into the standard $10$ tableaux representation, please?

Comment: The dual representation is a bit of a funny one in the young diagram picture. I believe it is the diagram which you could flip around and slot into the old diagram to make a rectangle of height $n$ and width that of the original diagram. So the dual of $10$ is three boxes stacked vertically (to make a vertical column of height 5) while the dual of $15$ is 8 boxes in two columns (to make a rectangle height 5, width 2) and so on. I can't find a source to confirm my pictorial idea is correct but it works for all the representations I have tested.

Answer (score 4):

Let $V=\Bbb C^5$ be the "natural" representation of $SU(5)$, with $\bar V$ the conjugate representation. Then

- $V\otimes V$ splits into $V\odot V$ and $V\wedge V$, symmetric and skew-symmetric products of dimensions 15 and 10. There was probably a print error, typo.
- $V\otimes \bar V$ splits in range and kernel of $a\times b \mapsto b^Ta$
- The 10 representation is, as per above, $V\wedge V$. Then the split-defining operation on $\bar V\otimes (V\wedge V)$ is $a\otimes (b\wedge c)\mapsto (a^Tb)c-(a^Tc)b$, with the range being all of $V$.
- $V\otimes(V∧V)$ splits into kernel and range of $a\otimes (b\wedge c)\mapsto a\wedge b\wedge c$, where $\Lambda^3V$ has dimension $10$.
- $(V∧V)\otimes(V∧V)$ similarly splits into kernel and range of $(a\wedge b)\otimes (c\wedge d)\mapsto (a\wedge b)\wedge (c\wedge d)$, where $\Lambda^4V$ has dimension $5$.

Comment: thank you very much, i think i understand Young's tableaux method now without the conjugation. Could you elaborate as how to convert the conjugate representation, eg. $\bar {10}$ into the standard $10$ tableaux representation, please?